# iOS Webapp - What keyboard key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications

How can I, with JavaScript, determine if the <kbd>Search</kbd> or <kbd>Done</kbd> buttons on the iOS keyboard are being tapped?

Comment: Try asking in the [iPhoneWebDev](http://groups.google.com/group/iphonewebdev/topics) Google Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if a Search or <kbd>Go</kbd> key is pressed listen for a `chr$(13)` keypress.

```
$('#searchBox').bind('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    //do something
  }
});
```